# Camera Parameters - iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv

Good evening folks of Stackoverflow,

I've been trying to find accurate data for calculating the focal parameter of [CameraParams](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d0a/structcv_1_1detail_1_1CameraParams.html#a9af414e5bbf7063c105ce8c9a2ec36ba) for quite some time but actively failed.

Here's what I got so far:

```
iPhone 7
Sensor width: 3.99mm
Focal length: 7.21mm
Random image: 400x400
```

**Calculation:**

`focal(in pixel) = image width(in pixel)*focal(in mm)/sensor width(mm)`

`focal = 400 * 7.21 / 3.99`

But that results to look very inaccurate. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html) gives you specs for each model of the iPhone camera.

You can also use the following code to get the spec for the camera when taking photos.

```
private func getCaptureDeviceSpec(_ videoDevice : AVCaptureDevice?) {
    if let deviceFormats = videoDevice?.formats {
        var width : Float = 0
        var height : Float = 0
        var fov : Float = 0
        for format in deviceFormats {
            if let deviceFormat = (format as? AVCaptureDeviceFormat) {
                let dim = deviceFormat.highResolutionStillImageDimensions
                if width < Float(dim.width) && height < Float(dim.height) {
                    width = Float(dim.width)
                    height = Float(dim.height)
                    fov = deviceFormat.videoFieldOfView
                }
            }
        }
        cameraSpec.width = width
        cameraSpec.height = height
        cameraSpec.fov = fov
    }
}
```

Comment: Since answering this I've realised you can actually just use `videoDevice.activeFormat` instead of searching through all the formats available.